# Playing image in the video tag of html 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, html5-audio

I have problem statement of showing 2-3 images between 2 videos for a specific amount of time using JavaScript. Do anyone have any idea how this can be achieved?
I have written the following code to do so but after the image gets played the video starts showing error and the videos get script after some time the script becomes completely instable

```
<html>
<head>
<title>video example</title>
</head>

<body onload="onload();">
   <video id="myVideo" height="400" width="400" autoplay onended="next();">
   </video>

   <img id="img" height="400" width="400" src="">

   <script>
     var video_list      = ['video/video1.mp4','video/1.png','video/2.png','video/video2.mp4','video/video3.mp4'];
      var video_index     = 0;
      var video_player    = null;
      var image           = null;
      var video = null;
      var length = video_list.length;
      var last_video = null;

      function next(){
          video = video_list[video_index];
          console.log(video);
          var ext = video.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
          if(ext=="mp4"||ext=="3gp")
          {
              last_video = video
              playvideo();
          }
          else
          {
              video_player.play();
              runimg();
          }
          video_index++;
          if(video_index==length)
          {
              video_index = 0;
          }
      }

      function runimg()
      {
          image.style.visibility = 'visible';
          video_player.style.visibility = 'hidden';
          image.setAttribute("src",video);
          setInterval(next,3000);
      }

      function playvideo()
      {
          image.style.visibility = 'hidden';
          video_player.style.visibility = 'visible';
          video_player.setAttribute("src", video);
          var playPromise = video_player.play();
          if (playPromise !== undefined) {
              playPromise.then(_ => {})
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                video_player.pause();
              });
          }
          else
          {
              video_player.pause();
          }
      }



      function onload(){
          console.log("body loaded");
          video_player        = document.getElementById("myVideo");
          image               = document.getElementById("img");
          next();
          // video_player.setAttribute("src", video_list[video_index]);
          // video_player.play();
      }

      function onVideoEnded(){
          console.log("video ended");
          video_player.setAttribute("src", video);
          video_player.play();
      }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please have a look on the code and suggest some solution

Comment: sry was still trying to find the errors in the code thats why didn't uploaded it

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to each video `ended` event, then show your image above the video container (using `position: absolute` in CSS, for example), and hide it / play the next video after a few seconds/minutes using `setTimeout`.

Please refer to [the doc](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) to learn more, you'll probably need it to switch to another video.

Comment: @Sushant I can assure you it's working, just tested here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xPZbwg

Comment: you put both image and video in the playlist array and then try because i think my playlist contains both while you have considered only videos in playlist